# Plotting solutions simultaneous equations found by NSolve gives unlabeled curves in the same color

Tags: plotting

Here is my code:

```
b = 1.5
d = 0.5
a = 0.5
tl = 0.5
Ah = 1.2
Al = 1.0
Plot[{Nh, Lh} /. 
  NSolve [{Ah + (Lh^((1 - b) d))*Nh^(-d) + (1 - a)*Nh^(-a) == 
     Al + ((1 - Lh)^((1 - b) d))*(1 - Nh)^(-d) + (1 - a) (1 - Nh)^(-a),
    (1 - th)*Lh^(-b) == (1 - tl)*(1 - Lh)^(-b)},
   {Nh, Lh}], {th, 0.1, 0.9}, PlotRange -> {{0.1, 0.9}, {0.2, 0.8}}]
```

Plot yields two curves of the same color and attempts to label them properly fail.  It's as if Plot thinks that it's graphing a single variable.  How can I get curves of different colors with individual labels?

Answer (score 5):

`Plot` has the attribute `HoldAll`. Normally this would be overcome by using `Evaluate` to force immediate evaluation of the first argument. However, the `NSolve` cannot evaluate until `th` is given a numeric value. The easiest solution is to calculate plot points and use `ListLinePlot`

```
Clear["Global`*"]

b = 3/2;
d = 1/2;
a = 1/2;
tl = 1/2;
Ah = 6/5;
Al = 1;

eqns = {Ah + (Lh^((1 - b) d))*Nh^(-d) + (1 - a)*Nh^(-a) == 
    Al + ((1 - Lh)^((1 - b) d))*(1 - Nh)^(-d) + (1 - a) (1 - Nh)^(-a), (1 - 
       th)*Lh^(-b) == (1 - tl)*(1 - Lh)^(-b)};

sol[th_?NumericQ] := 
 NSolveValues[{Ah + (Lh^((1 - b) d))*Nh^(-d) + (1 - a)*Nh^(-a) == 
     Al + ((1 - Lh)^((1 - b) d))*(1 - Nh)^(-d) + (1 - a) (1 - Nh)^(-a), (1 - 
        th)*Lh^(-b) == (1 - tl)*(1 - Lh)^(-b)}, {Nh, Lh}][[1]]

data = Transpose@Table[Thread[{th, sol[th]}],
    {th, 1/10, 9/10, 1/20}];

ListLinePlot[data, PlotRange -> {{0.1, 0.9}, {0.2, 0.8}},
 PlotLegends -> Placed[{Nh, Lh}, {.9, .45}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing, thank you!

Comment: Actually, when I run this code, the curves don't show up, although the labels do.  Am I missing some graphics input command?

Comment: I just copied the above into a notebook and it evaluated as expected. The definition of `eqns` is unnecessary since I didn't use `eqns` to replace the equations in the `NSolveValues`. `NSolveValues` was introduced in v12.3. If you have an older version, replace it with `{Nh, Lh} /. NSolve`

Comment: Works now!  Thanks a million (I have version 12.1)

Answer (score 4):

We set

```
plot=Plot[{Nh, Lh} /. 
  NSolve [{Ah + (Lh^((1 - b) d))*Nh^(-d) + (1 - a)*Nh^(-a) == 
     Al + ((1 - Lh)^((1 - b) d))*(1 - Nh)^(-d) + (1 - a) (1 - Nh)^(-a),
    (1 - th)*Lh^(-b) == (1 - tl)*(1 - Lh)^(-b)},
   {Nh, Lh}], {th, 0.1, 0.9}, PlotRange -> {{0.1, 0.9}, {0.2, 0.8}}]
```

Then

```
Block[{e = 1}, plot /. Line[pts_] :> {ColorData[97][e++], Line[pts]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing, thank you!